# WebClient and Tasks not retrieving new content yet new content is available?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

Even though I am creating new instances of WebClient, and following standard procedures to ensure that the WebClient is removed by GC, which shouldn't even matter: the webclient retrieves content from my server that it previously retrieved, and only restarting the app will it allow new content from my server to be retrieved. The content is a simple text file string, no fancy caching since it works on WinRT just fine.

This is a mystery, as I am trying to make a ChatBox; I need to refresh to gain new content yet the WebClient returns content it retrieved the first time.

My Code:

```
    public async Task<string> RetrieveDocURL(Uri uri)
    {

        return await DownloadStringTask(new WebClient(), uri);
    }

    /*
    public async Task<byte[]> RetrieveImageURL(string url)
    {
        return await _webClient.GetByteArrayAsync(url);
    }
     * */

    private Task<string> DownloadStringTask(WebClient client, Uri uri)
    {
        var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<string>();

        client.DownloadStringCompleted += (o, e) =>
            {
                if (e.Error != null)
                    tcs.SetException(e.Error);
                else
                    tcs.SetResult(e.Result);
            };

        client.DownloadStringAsync(uri);

        return tcs.Task;
    }
```

Comment: The WebClient's caching strategy is really aggressive. If you're querying the same URL each time, you should consider adding a random parameter at the end. Something like `"http://www.yourserver.com/yourService/?nocache=" + DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks`

Comment: Thanks! This is the solution! Add this to the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The WebClient's caching strategy is really aggressive. If you're querying the same URL each time, you should consider adding a random parameter at the end. Something like:

```
"http://www.yourserver.com/yourService/?nocache=" + DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks
```